# Build errors in Eclipse with JAXB generated classes

Tags: java, eclipse, jaxb, m2eclipse, hotdeploy

I'm experiencing a strange problem where Eclipse can't find JAXB generated classes when debugging on JBoss.

Here the steps that lead to the obstacle.

1. I start my JBoss 4.2.3 in debug mode
2. I deploy my Java project to the server
3. I perform a minor change in the source code (like appending a whitespace)
4. Eclipse builds the project a new
5. Eclipse can't find the JAXB generated classes of an external library
6. Build errors in Eclipse
7. Hot code replacement fails

When I don't start JBoss in debug mode, everything works fine.

I suspect that the problem lies in the interplay of Eclipse and the JAXB generated classes. I'm using Eclipse Indigo and the m2eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [JBossAS Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools), creating a new server from this plugin and deploying my `.war` exploded has somehow mitigated this problem.